# Getting started creating digital music

Tags: windows, gratis, music, music-production

I have played piano for a while, understand music theory, etc. and can write songs.

I don't know what the best way to do this is, but I want to be able to use some program where I can put in a series of notes of different lengths (preferably for all different instruments) and it will spit out a music file for that. I am very new to music development and I am not sure if this is possible, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be ideal.

Also just to make it clear, I have no keyboards or instruments that I can use to plug in to my computer, I am looking to be able to do it all within the computer. I am running Windows 10, and I want it to be free, and I can export and use the songs for anything I want (no copyrights).

Thanks!

[EDIT] Still looking for help, thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have in mind when writing "music file"? What formats would you preferably be interested in? Midi, Wave, a LaTeX music score…?

Comment: I'm kind of new to this and not really sure about what different music formats mean. But from what I know .wav and .mp3 are the most widely used formats so ideally those.

Comment: That already answers half of it: you mean "sound files" to listen to – not "music scores" for musicians to play after :) [Midi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) is something in between the two. Some instruments can use midi files and "auto-play" the scores – and some editors show you the scores and let you edit them. [Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) files and MP3 (lossy compression, so smaller file size) are mainly to listen to. There are many more formats, but I was mainly asking for the "category" (so Midi vs Wav).

Comment: Anyways yeah still looking for reccomendations

Answer (score 2):

Try [MuseScore](https://musescore.org/).  Free of charge, very capable.

Answer (score 0):

If commercial software is acceptable, you might want to take a look at Myriad's [Melody Assistant](https://www.myriad-online.com/en/products/melody.htm) and [Harmony Assistant](https://www.myriad-online.com/en/products/harmony.htm) (I use the latter). Harmony Assistant is the more capable version of the two, a superset of Melody Assistant. Both programs allow you to enter your music as standard notation in a point-and-click interface, and can generate mp3 file as well as saving your projects in editable form. There are two add-ons that I recommend; the [Gold Sound Base](https://www.myriad-online.com/en/products/gold.htm) provides higher-quality "renderings" of instruments, and [Virtual Singer](https://www.myriad-online.com/en/products/virtualsinger.htm) which allows you to add synthesized voices singing your lyrics to a song. All of these are available for Windows, MacOSX, and Linux; I use them on Windows (starting with Windows 7).

You can hear [one of the organs in the Gold Sound Base playing the hymn *Melita*](http://www.freelancetraveller.com/magazine/2018-0708/spacers-hymn-organ.mp3) at http://www.freelancetraveller.com/magazine/2018-0708/spacers-hymn-organ.mp3, and some ["spacer" lyrics have been added using Virtual Singer and sung](http://www.freelancetraveller.com/magazine/2018-0708/spacers-hymn-vocals.mp3) at http://www.freelancetraveller.com/magazine/2018-0708/spacers-hymn-vocals.mp3.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding to my question. I took a look at Harmony Assistant and it looks like you have to buy a license for it. Sorry if I didn't make it clear but I was looking for free software.

Comment: Well, you did say "Ideally...free", which is why I started with "If commercial software is acceptable...". "Ideally..." implies that it's strongly preferred, but not necessarily mandatory.

Comment: So sorry, I didn't word it very clearly you are correct, I have updated it to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the production quality of the music, a scorewriter like MuseScore is not sufficient.

The type of software you are looking for is called a [Digital Audio Workstation (DAW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation).

One example of a free DAW is [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) (which runs on windows despite its name). This is probably the best starting point for you.
Alternatively, the commercial software [FL Studio](https://www.image-line.com/) has a free demo with no time restriction that lets you render audio files but does not let you save project files.

Both programs do not require a keyboard or any other special hardware, and both allow you to export audio in all standard file formats.

In DAWs, musical instruments come in the form of [VST plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology#VST_plugins).
Most DAWs already have a set of VST plugins pre-installed, but you should in any case try to expand this collection.
Luckily, there is a good amount of free VST plugins for both "real" and synthetic instruments on the internet.